# Correct way to detect Mobile brands through Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I would like to detect LG and HTC mobiles as our client have particularly asked for a functionality for these mobile brands only. I have tried with the following code and it is working fine. But i just wanted to know if this is a correct way to detect the above mobile brands. Thanks in Advance.

```
   if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('HTC') > -1){
            alert("HTC");
           }
        else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('LG') > -1){
             alert("LG");
         }
```